# Tripos Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Show that
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\sin^2 x}{e^{2mx}(\cos x-m\sin x)^2}dx=\frac{1}{2m(1+m^2)}\left[\frac{1+m}{1-m}e^{-m\frac{\pi}{2}}-1\right]$$
This problem is from Edwards, Treatise on Integral Calculus II, pg.187.

It is a definite integral and is not likely to find the indefinite integral, at this point in the book Edwards has introduces the tricks of substituting $\frac{\pi}{4}-x$ for $x$, and expansion in series (and of course parts). Unfortunately, I haven't been able to make these tricks work out. My method has been to expand $\frac{\tan^2 x}{(1-m\tan x)^2}$ as a series in $m\tan x$, and integrate termwise but so far without success. Does anybody have any good ideas?

Comment: You give the source and what tools are in the given section, and an idea of what you have tried. I think that meets several of the requirements for context. One question I have is: are there any restrictions on $m$? My guess is the $|m|\lt1$, but it would be good if that were stated in the question.

Comment: Yeah, there is no information on $m$ given.

Comment: If $m\ge1$, it seems the integral diverges near $x=\tan^{-1}(1/m)\in(0,\pi/4]$.

Comment: (Reposting due to typo) In the same problem, Edwards also lists the form $$\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\cos^2 x}{e^{2mx}(\sin x+m \cos x)^2}=\frac{1}{2m(1+m^2)}\left[\frac{1-m}{1+m}e^{-m\pi/2}+1\right]$$
It's not immediately obvious that this is equivalent to the first integral, and so it seems worth listing as well.

Comment: I solved it ! HaHaHa.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Then you should answer your own question, writing down the correct answer so everybody could have the pleasure of reading it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually not very difficult to obtain the correct antiderivative (for some reason i use $a$ for the integral parameter, not $m$).
The only non-trivial observation here is how to write the more compelx part of the integral as a derivative ($'$ denotes differentation w.r.t. $x$):

$$I = (2a)^{-1}\int \left(\frac{\cos(x)+a \sin(x)}{\cos(x)-a \sin(x)}\right)' \sin^2(x)e^{-2 a x}$$

integrating by parts, we can just cancel the annoying stuff:

$$
(2a)I = e^{-2 a x}\sin^2(x)\frac{\cos(x)+a \sin(x)}{\cos(x)-a \sin(x)} -\\
\int \left(\frac{\cos(x)+a \sin(x)}{\color{red}{\cos(x)-a \sin(x)}}\right)( \color{red}{\cos(x)-a \sin(x)}) \sin(x)e^{-2 a x} 
$$

the remaining integral is elementary:

$$
e^{2 a x}(2a)I =\sin^2(x)\frac{\cos(x)+a \sin(x)}{\cos(x)-a \sin(x)}+\frac{(\cos(x)+a \sin(x))^2}{a^2+1}
$$

this can be [brought into](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28cos%28x%29%20%2B%20a%20sin%28x%29%29%5E2%29%2F%281%20%2B%20a%5E2%29%2Bsin%28x%29%5E2%28%28cos%28x%29%20%2B%20a%20sin%28x%29%29%2F%28%28cos%28x%29-%20a%20sin%28x%29%29%29%29) the form indicated by @Claude Leibovici, but i don't have the right temper for stupid algebra like that at the moment

Comment: This is really great method.

Answer (score 13):

We'll first remove the trigonometric functions since it's easier to work with rational functions, but if you can see (without reverse engineering) how to split the integral in the original form then there's no need to do this.
$$I=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} \frac{\sin^2 x e^{-2mx}}{(m\sin x-\cos x)^2}dx\overset{\cot x \to x}=\int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-2m\cot^{-1}x}}{1+x^2}\frac{dx}{(m-x)^2}$$
Forcing a partial fraction to have $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ and $\frac{1}{(m-x)^2}$ separately yields:
$$I=\frac{1}{1+m^2}\int_1^\infty e^{-2m\cot^{-1} x}\left(\color{blue}{\frac{1}{1+x^2}\frac{m+x}{m-x}}+\color{red}{\frac{1}{(m-x)^2}}\right)dx$$

Finally integrating by parts the first term gives:
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-2m\cot^{-1} x}}{\color{blue}{1+x^2}}\color{blue}{\frac{m+x}{m-x}}dx = \int_1^\infty \left(\frac{e^{-2m\cot^{-1} x}}{2m}\right)'\frac{m+x}{m-x}dx$$
$$=\frac{e^{-2m\cot^{-1} x}}{2m}\frac{m+x}{m-x}\bigg|_1^\infty -\int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-2m\cot^{-1} x}}{\color{red}{(m-x)^2}}dx$$
$$\Rightarrow I=\frac{1}{1+m^2}\frac{e^{-2m\cot^{-1} x}}{2m}\frac{m+x}{m-x}\bigg|_1^\infty=\frac{1}{2m(1+m^2)}\left(\frac{1+m}{1-m}e^{-m\pi/2}-1\right)$$

Comment: I cant see your integration by parts, what is the part that is integrated ? the blue expression ? I dont see its integral.

Comment: With the colors I was trying to show that we arrive back at that integral after integrating by parts.

When integrating by parts there is: $$\int e^{-2m\cot^{-1}x} \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx =\frac{1}{2m}e^{-2m\cot^{-1}x} + C$$
$$\left(\frac{m+x}{m-x}\right)'=\frac{2m}{(m-x)^2}$$

Comment: Yeah ok I see now, It is a good practice to write these things as $\int \frac{m+x}{m-x}d(e^{-2m\cot^{-1} x})$

Answer (score 4):

*Too long for a comment.*

The idea of writing
$$\frac{\tan^2 (x)}{(1-m\tan (x))^2}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty (n-1)\, m^{n-2}\, \tan^n(x)$$ was appealing.

But the problem of
$$I_n=\int_0^{\frac \pi 4}e^{-2mx}\tan^n(x)\,dx$$ is a nightmare since $2 i^n I_n$ write
$$\frac{i \Gamma (i m) \Gamma (n+1) \, _2F_1(i m,n;i m+n+1;-1)}{\Gamma (i
   m+n+1)}-\frac{e^{-\frac{\pi  m}{2}} F_1(i m;n,-n;i m+1;-i,i)}{m}$$ where appear the gaussian hypergeometric function as well as the Appell hypergeometric function of two variables. I prefer not to think about the problem of the summation.

On the other hand, the antiderivative is quite nice
$$\int\frac{\sin^2 (x)}{e^{2mx}(\cos (x)-m\sin (x))^2}dx=\frac{e^{-2mx} }{2m(1+m^2)}\,\,\frac{\cos (x)+m \sin (x)}{\cos (x)-m \sin (x)}$$

Comment: I am surprised that there is an anti derivative. Can you post a derivation ?

Comment: Well actually I think I have one.

Answer (score 4):

Well the anti derivative exists. As pointed out by Claude Leibovici. I had just assumed that as it was a chapter on definite integrals, they would not give examples where the indefinite integral exists. Anyway here is a calculation of the anti derivative. The result on the last line.

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\int e^{-2mx}\frac{\tan^2 x}{(1-m\tan x)^2}dx
&=\int e^{-2mx}\frac{\sec^2 x}{(1-m\tan x)^2}dx
-\int e^{-2mx}\frac{1}{(1-m\tan x)^2}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{m}\int e^{-2mx}d\frac{1}{(1-m\tan x)}
-\int e^{-2mx}\frac{1}{(1-m\tan x)^2}dx\\
&=e^{-2mx}\frac{1}{m(1-m\tan x)}+2\int e^{-2mx}\frac{1}{(1-m\tan x)}dx\\
&-\int e^{-2mx}\frac{1}{(1-m\tan x)^2}dx\\
&=e^{-2mx}\frac{1}{m(1-m\tan x)}+2\int e^{-2mx}\frac{1-m\tan x}{(1-m\tan x)^2}dx\\
&-\int e^{-2mx}\frac{1}{(1-m\tan x)^2}dx\\
&=e^{-2mx}\frac{1}{m(1-m\tan x)}+\int e^{-2mx}\frac{1-2m\tan x}{(1-m\tan x)^2}dx\\
&=e^{-2mx}\frac{1}{m(1-m\tan x)}+\int e^{-2mx}\frac{1-2m\tan x+m^2\tan^2 x}{(1-m\tan x)^2}dx\\
&-m^2\int e^{-2mx}\frac{\tan^2 x}{(1-m\tan x)^2}dx
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

So $$(1+m^2)\int e^{-2mx}\frac{\tan^2 x}{(1-m\tan x)^2}dx=
e^{-2mx}\frac{1}{m(1-m\tan x)}+\int e^{-2mx}dx$$
$$=
e^{-2mx}\frac{1}{m(1-m\tan x)}-\frac{1}{2m}e^{-2mx}$$
$$=
\frac{1}{2m}e^{-2mx}\frac{1+m\tan x}{1-m\tan x}$$

So finally,

$$\int e^{-2mx}\frac{\tan^2 x}{(1-m\tan x)^2}dx=
\frac{1}{2m(1+m^2)}e^{-2mx}\frac{1+m\tan x}{1-m\tan x}$$

Comment: Where is your true derivation of the result? This is just a sort of Leibovici's tail. You claimed you solved it 20 hours ago and yet we are not seeing *your* solution...

Comment: This is my solution, after Claude's comment I realized it computes the anti derivative. I had originally been evaluating as I proceeded. The problem in conceptual, I just wasnt thinking of anti derivatives.

Comment: You are saying "the anti derivative exists"... of course it exists. What you mean is: a closed form exists. :)